# Volatility failed to scan memory dump of Virtualbox

Tags: volatility, memoryanalyzer

I done a memory dump with elf format using Virtualbox manager.

```
VBoxManage debugvm "image_name" dumpguestcore --filename test.elf
```

It worked well. Then I try to analyze the dump with volatility.

The imageinfo worked well and get the result.

```
volatility-2.2.standalone.exe -f test.elf imageinfo
Volatile Systems Volatility Framework 2.2
Determining profile based on KDBG search...
          Suggested Profile(s) : WinXPSP2x86, WinXPSP3x86 (Instantiated with WinXPSP2x86)
                     AS Layer1 : FileAddressSpace (C:\work\volatility\test.elf)
                      PAE type : No PAE
                           DTB : 0x2f3000L
                          KDBG : 0x5461d0
          Number of Processors : 0
     Image Type (Service Pack) : -
             KUSER_SHARED_DATA : 0xffdf0000L
```

It is failed When I tried to using pslist.

```
volatility-2.2.standalone.exe -f test.elf --profile=WinXPSP3x86 pslist
Volatile Systems Volatility Framework 2.2
No suitable address space mapping found
Tried to open image as:
 LimeAddressSpace: lime: need base
 WindowsHiberFileSpace32: No base Address Space
 WindowsCrashDumpSpace64: No base Address Space
 WindowsCrashDumpSpace32: No base Address Space
 AMD64PagedMemory: No base Address Space
 JKIA32PagedMemory: No base Address Space
 JKIA32PagedMemoryPae: No base Address Space
 IA32PagedMemoryPae: Module disabled
 IA32PagedMemory: Module disabled
 LimeAddressSpace: Invalid Lime header signature
 WindowsHiberFileSpace32: No xpress signature found
 WindowsCrashDumpSpace64: Header signature invalid
 WindowsCrashDumpSpace32: Header signature invalid
 AMD64PagedMemory: Incompatible profile WinXPSP3x86 selected
 JKIA32PagedMemory: Failed valid Address Space check
 JKIA32PagedMemoryPae: Failed valid Address Space check
 IA32PagedMemoryPae: Module disabled
 IA32PagedMemory: Module disabled
 FileAddressSpace: Must be first Address Space
```

Could anyone help to look at the issue why Volatility could not find "suitable address space mapping found" ???

Great thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Solved, virtualbox memory dump used ELF64 format, but volatility 2.2 didn't support it. The plugin here http://wiki.yobi.be/wiki/RAM_analysis could be used to support ELF64 format.